# Error in using Range from @xlfunc

Tags: xlwings

I work with xlwings 0.6.4. These lines work as documented if executed from the python prompt:

```
from xlwings import xlfunc, Range, Workbook
wb = Workbook.active()
Range('B1').value = 'set'
```

But if I put the code into @xlfunc macro, load the UDF in Excel (Excel2016 in Windows7) and execute "=test_set()", I obtain an error.

```
from xlwings import xlfunc, Range, Workbook

@xlfunc
def test_set():
    wb = Workbook.active()
    Range('B1').value = 'set'
    return 'set ok!'
```

And the error is:

```
pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 277, in _
Invoke_
    return self._invoke_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 282, in _
invoke_
    return S_OK, -1, self._invokeex_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args, None, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 585, in _
invokeex_
    return func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\server.py", line 179, in Call
    return ToVariant(obj(*pargs, **kwargs))
  File "c:\users\az\projects\test_set\test_set.py", line 6, in test_set
    Range('B1').value = 'set'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 901, in value
    self.row1, self.col1, row2, col2), data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 273, in set_v
alue
    xl_range.Value = data
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in
__setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -214682
7284), None)
```

Please, help! What do I do wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

User defined functions can only manipulate the calling cells which means that you can read via `xlwing.Range` but you can't assign a value to it. You can only change the value of cells by returning a single value (like a number or string) or a 2d shape like a nested list or a numpy array for array formulas.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. (Is it explained in the documentation? Did I miss it?) That means UDFs are less powerful than macros. OK.

Comment: But this code did not work (it just sets a single cell to "1-Jan-00"): `@xlfunc
def test_set():
    wb = Workbook.active()
    return [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Comment: It's the standard behaviour of Excel UDFs, but I ll make sure the docs improve on that topic. Regarding your *did not work* comment: Reformat the cell to `General` instead of date and you need to use array formulas on the side of Excel, see [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/udfs.html#array-formulas-i-without-numpy)